# How to re-scale the counts in a matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a matplotlib histogram that works fine.

```
hist_bin_width = 4
on_hist = plt.hist(my_data,bins=range(-100, 200,hist_bin_width),alpha=.3,color='#6e9bd1',label='on')
```

All I want to do is to rescale by a factor of, say, 2. I don't want to change the bin width, or to change the y axis labels. I want to take the counts in all the bins (e.g. bin 1 has 17 counts) and multiply by 2 so that bin 1 now has 34 counts in it.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it's just a simple rescaling of the y-axis, this must be possible. The complication arises because Matplotlib's [hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) computes *and* draws the histogram, making it difficult to intervene. However, as the documentation also notes, you can use the `weights` parameter to "draw a histogram of data that has already been binned". You can bin the data in a first step with Numpy's [histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function. Applying the scaling factor is then straightforward:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(0)
data = numpy.random.normal(50, 20, 10000)
(counts, bins) = numpy.histogram(data, bins=range(101))

factor = 2
pyplot.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=factor*counts)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

`pyplot.hist`'s `weights` argument can be used to weight each data point with a factor like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

data = np.random.normal(50, 20, 10000)

factor = 2
hist_bin_width = 40
plt.hist(data, bins=range(-100, 200, hist_bin_width), 
               weights=factor*np.ones_like(data))
plt.show()
```